TypeError: item.toLocaleDateString() is not a function | Works on my machine but throws errors for other users
In my team I am trying to develop example pages for custom date picker components. In the example page, I have a state variable that is an array of type Date|null. When I go to output the array, I use a map function to turn each date in the array into a formatted string, if not null.
This is my state variable:
const [multiMonthDates,setMultiMonthDates] = useState<(Date|null)[]>([])
This is how I attempt to output the selected dates:
<h1>{multiMonthDates.map((item)=>(item?.toLocaleDateString())?.concat(", "))}</h1>
When I run this locally, everything works as expected but I have had other users tell me that they are getting the error:
TypeError: item.toLocaleDateString() is not a function
I would assume this is because it is trying to call the function on a null value, but I am using the optional operator, so I don't know why that would be the case. Regardless, I have no idea why I am not experiencing the same error.
I have tried deleting the branch from my local machine and redownloading it, but nothing changed, it still works for me fine.

This is saying it's not defined, which says to me that at runtime item is not a Date object. log the type of item as you map them.

@HereticMonkey When I map the type of item I get 'object'

You could log item instanceof Date to be sure it's a Date.

@HereticMonkey yes each item returns true. Though it has always been working as expected on my computer so I can't speak for the users who are experiencing the issue.

It may have to do with how the dates are being created; are you doing new Date(string) by any chance? You may have different regional settings that your users, which will cause parsing to differ...

@HereticMonkey The dates are being created by being converted from DateObject. There is another mapping function that does (item) => item.toDate()

I don't know what that means, but if some people are not getting date objects and some are, that's where I'd start looking...
